# How do I obtain the data to train my ML model?

Tags: machine-learning, web-scraping, data-collection

I am building a machine learning model that would suggest attractions in a specific location.

I have most of the details worked out. However, I still need to collect the data of the attractions to train my model.

Is there somewhere I could find a dataset for this (I already checked Kaggle)? If not which websites should I scrape?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to scrape data, twitter probably is the easiest to start. You can use [twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api) to get any tweet that contain a specific keyword or hashtag, input your desired location as the keyword and scrape it using tweepy, i would suggest you to scrape from a specific account like Influencer or travel blog to get data about attraction.

Applying to get twitter API might take several days, and you can only scrape tweet within a time range of a weeks. older than that you need to sign up to their premium subscription.